# Random walk with increments that have an exponential distribution. $S_n = \sum_1^n(X_i-1)$, $X_i \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a random walk $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -1)$ where $P( X_i\leq t) = 1- e^{-t}$, that is $X_i$ are iid with exponential distribution and mean 1. I am trying to figure out what $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{1}_{S_n>0}$$
is ( $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator of the event $A$). By the central limit theorem I know that $1_{S_n>0}$ converges in expectation to 0.5, and I know by the SLLN that $S_n \to 0$ almost surely, but what I cannot figure out is whether $\liminf_n \{S_n > 0\}$ occurs with probability 0.5, i.e if $S_n > 0$ for all but finitely many $n$ half the time. Intuitively it seems like if for some large $n$, $S_n$ is positive, it would be very unlikely to get back below 0 because the steps down are bounded ($X_i \geq 0$) and are independent..but yeah, I just can't figure out a rigorous way to show that. Can anyone provide some assistance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Law of Iterated Logarithms, which A.S. so kindly pointed out to me, we have: 
$$ P\left(\limsup {\{ \frac{S_n }{\sqrt{n \log\log n}} >0 \}} \right)=1. $$
Now, using the fact that the $\limsup$ of indicators is just the indicator of the $\limsup$ it follows that 
$$\limsup 1_{\{S_n >0\}} = \limsup 1_{\{ \frac{S_n }{\sqrt{n \log\log n}} >0 \}} = 1$$ and similarly the $\liminf$ is 0, thus $1_{S_n>0}$ does not converge (almost surely).